# In java Generics, how to extend an interface instead of a class

Tags: java

I would like to make something similar to `Class<? extends MyParentClass>>` 
but using an interface, something like

```
Class<? implements MyInterfaceClass>
```

but i got this error:

```
- Incorrect number of arguments for type Class<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <?, 
     MyInterfaceClass>
```

but It seems that is not possible ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html - "Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either 'extends' (as in classes) or 'implements' (as in interfaces)."

Comment: Could you show us code which generates this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But in world of generics there is no `implements` but only `extends` and `super` so simply use `extends` (even if you are working with interface).

```
Class<? extends MyInterfaceClass>
//      ^^^^^^^
```

Example:

```
Class<? extends Runnable> taskClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

You still use the word extends instead of implements

For example

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

public class Demo {
    private Class<? extends MyInterface> myClass;
}
```